# How do I line up multiple values from System.out.print into columns neatly?

Tags: java, system.out

In Java, how would I line up my file/sizes so that both columns start at the exact same column position?

Here is my code thus far:

```
System.out.println(child.getName() + " \t\t" + child.length() + " , ");
```

it makes this output(pic):

[image]

However, I would like both columns to line up so that it's like a table-of-contents in a book.

Do I use format-specifierrs?

thanks

Comment: @Pshemo - Ok I'm studying that one. thank you so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
System.out.printf("%40s %d,%n",child.getName(),child.length());
```

Where 40 is the minimum width.  Change this as you see fit.

Edit: using %n instead of \n for OS specific linebreak.

Comment: Instead of `\n` it is better to use `%n` to make line separator OS dependant.

Comment: @Pshemo - Wait, I didn't know you can use %n instead. you mean "OS independant" though right?    thanks!

Comment: Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html right before "Date/time conversions"

Comment: I meant that `%n` will represent same result as `System.lineSeparator()` so on Windows it will be `\r\n` on Linux `\n` on Mac OS `\r`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `System.out.printf` and specify widths in your format string. Note that in the case of strings that are too long to fit in the column, the formatter will still overflow the specified width.